# Capistrano isn't applying path environment to second command

Tags: path, capistrano, sshkit

My Capistrano deployments are hanging on the second command in a composite command.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/5986983915163e6681f2546bf6fad599d58cd024/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb#L59

At the point that SSHKit tries to run the following command:

`cd /home/lawfm/deployments/staging/repo && git rev-parse`

I get a
`bash: git: command not found` error.

I believe the issue is documented here:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/675

My deploy was working in 3.0.1, but an upgrade to 3.1 introduced the error. At first, I read that pty was now on by default, so I set:

`set :pty, false`

Unfortunately, it seems neither .bash_profile nor .profile are being loaded, so any attempt to augment the PATH there have been fruitless.

I can't seem to figure out a way to set the path or even map the git command directly since it's the second command.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out a way to fix the path not being applied to the second command, but I did place the PATH definition in my .bashrc file instead of .bash_profile and it now works.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me a lot. I was trying to set a server-specific path in my Capistrano file which was really very much going against Capistrano philosophy. :)